# Setting an interval on ModifyListener for Text in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I am trying to trigger ModifyListener on changes made in the text fields in set intervals. Is there a way to do this in SWT with Java ?

Comment: No, modify events are generated as soon as the text is modified. Perhaps you should [edit] your question and explain why you want to do this.

Comment: I see. I wanted to do this because I wanted to optimize text validation: the way entered text is validated is quite complicated at the moment and validating it every time a user modifies the text is very inefficient. Thank you for getting back to me :)